# Code showing no output whatsoever (python)

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to make a little Fibonacci game where the user guesses a set amount of steps. I'm trying to make a functioning Fibonacci generator to make the lists to refer to later, but nothing is showing up. I'm sure I'm returning the values. What am I doing wrong?

```
""" Core Fibonacci Code

a = int(input("How many steps of fibonacci would you like? "))

def fibonacci(counter):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    count = 2
    print (a)
    print (b)
    fib = [0, 1]
    while (counter > count):
        c = a + b
        print (c)
        a = b
        b = c
        count += 1

fibonacci(a)

"""

def fibonacci(counter):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    count = 2
    print (a)
    print (b)
    fib_list.append = a
    fib_list.append = b
    while (counter > count):
        c = a + b
        fib_list.append = c
        a = b
        b = c
        count += 1

def homescreen():
    print = ("Which gamemode would you like to play?")
    print = ("EASY - 10 Steps")
    print = ("MEDIUM - 25 Steps")
    print = ("HARD - 50 Steps")
    request = input("")
    if request is "Easy" or "easy":
        z = 10
    elif request is "Medium" or "medium":
        z = 25
    elif request is "Hard" or "hard":
        z = 50
    return z


homescreen()
fibonacci(z)
print (fib_list)
```

Comment: What's with the `print =`?

Comment: If you're returning something from a function, then, while you use that function, you need to use a variable to store that returned value.

For eg, `z = homescreen()`

Comment: well your fib_list is in the in the wrong scope. either declare it outside your `fibonacci(counter)` function or return it and get it with `fib_list = fibonacci(z)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `print("Which gamemode would you like to play?")` and not `print=`.

You use such format when your returning something from the called function.
eg:

```
def foo():
        #Something
       return y
 x=foo()
```

**Note** :
Use the function `append()`, dont use `lib_list.append=a`.
Also declare `lib_list` outside the function `fibonacci()` as you're mentioning it in the function call outside of the function.